# Variance of the first return time of a simple random walk on an hypercube graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, stochastic-processes, random, spectral-graph-theory

I am trying to solve this problem....

I have a simple random walk on a $d$-cube (finite graph). At each vertex of the graph, the particle chooses one of $d$ edges equally likely. I need to calculate the variance of first return time, i.e. the variance (or second moment) of the time that takes until the particle is at the vertex it started. I know that for the $i^{th}$ vertex second moment return time is:

$
w_{ii}=-\frac{1}{\pi_i}+\frac{2z_{ii}}{\pi_i^2}
$

where  $\pi_i$ is the steady state probability and $z_{ii}$ is $(i,i)$ element of the fundamental matrix (fundamental matrix: $Z=(I-(A-P))^{-1}$, $A$ is transition probability matrix and $P$ is steady state probability matrix). I just do not know how to  find $z_{ii}$ in terms of $d$. Can anybody help to find the exact answer or an upper bound?

Comment: The return time distribution depends on the vertex, even for a regular graph. So you cannot express $z_{i,i}$ in terms of $d$ alone.

Comment: Thanks for your response Chris. When I write the transition matrix and the steady state matrix, both are quite symmetric, I mean there is no difference between the elements for different vertices; so I think $z_{ii}$ should also be the same for all vertices.

Comment: But the distribution of returns to $i$ in $G$ is determined by the characteristic polynomial of $G$ with vertex $i$ deleted and this is, in general, dependent on $i$. The Frucht graph http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht_graph will serve as an example.

Comment: This is actually a $d$-dimensional cube, do you think this information can help to find the solution. I would really appreciate any help/hints you could give me.

Comment: The fact that it is $d$-cube makes a great difference; all my objections vanish.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited my question to make it clear, but I still cannot find the answer.